# VS2022 with GitHub Copilot adding random spaces while typing

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

Not sure if this is a Visual Studio 2022 bug or a GitHub Copilot bug, but frequently when I'm typing, it will just add a ton of spaces in the middle of the text wherever the cursor happens to be.  It's gotten to the point where it's really affecting my productivity.  For an example, see here:

[image]

I was just typing the word "Console" and it added those spaces in the middle on its own.

Any ideas on which settings I might tweak in VS to remove this annoying behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be a keyboard bug as well. Do you encounter the problem in other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not experienced the same thing as you, but I would check the settings that you see with the suggested snippet.  My guess is you are having conflicts between Visual Studio IntelliCode and GitHub Copilot.

You should try unchecking "Show whole line completions" as a start.

[image]

Comment: Copilot already disables that option when it's installed and active for the current doc.

Comment: Copilot didn't automatically disable it for me.  After some time working with it, unchecking the box seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version 1.31.0.1 should work better in this regard. Which version are you on?

Comment: That is the version I'm on, as reported by VS's Extension manager.